# Check out old commit - two branches - repo tool

Tags: git, repository

I have two repos - a `code` repo and a `test_scripts` repo - that are closely tied (a change in the code usually necessitates a change in the scripts).

I've looked into the Android `repo` tool as an option to "synchronise" things like branch creation and sending code for Gerrit review. It looks good. But now I'm looking for a way to similarly synchronise the checking out of old commits. For example: I want to check if a bug existed in an older commit to `code`, thus I'll need the version of `test_scripts` that existed at that time. Is this possible with `repo` or another tool?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to use submodules. Adding the `test_scripts` repo as a submodule of the `code` repo allows you to have each commit of the `code` repo point to a specific commit in the `test_scripts` repo.

Here is a good introduction: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: I'm trying to avoid submodules at all costs, as I've heard terrible things about them. Additionally `test_scripts` is internal only so I couldn't include it as a submodule in `code`. On the other hand, `code` changes far more frequently, so placing `code` in `test_scripts` would mean every commit would require a `submodule update` command be executed. Not ideal. :(